# Автоматическая смена кодировки скриптов в Unity3d при первом появлении кириллицы в скрипте

Tags: unity3d, utf-8

1. Все шаблоны скриптов в Unity храняться в `UTF-8`.
2. Создаем новый скрипт - `UTF-8`
3. Открываем в Visual Studio - `UTF-8`
4. Пишем код - `UTF-8`
5. **Начинаем 1-ый раз что-то писать на русском (комменты) - Windows 1251**
6. Через Notepad++ преобразую файл в `UTF-8` и далее кодировка не меняется, даже если буду еще дописывать комменты кирилицей.

Кто-то может подсказать? Впервые с такой проблемой столкнулся. Может кто в курсе как ее решить (кроме как создать новый проект и туда все перетащить).

Comment: Пока решил проблему костыльным методом. Добавил в шаблон скриптов Unity3d коммент на кириллице. Так образом у Visual Studio не возникает вопросов о том, что это UTF-8, а не Windows-1251.  Все надеюсь есть более адекватное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы. Помог учитель.
Во первых я открыл PowerShell . Вставил туда этот код [System.Text.Encoding]::Default . У меня система была с кодировкой 1251

После сделал так:
Панель управления - Часы регионы- Изменения форматов даты и времени - Дополнительно -Меняем на Английский - Перезагружаем

После система стала с кодировкой 1152 и новые скрипты с добавлением русским комментариев отображались нормально . При этом хоть и написано что система на английском, она у меня на русском осталась [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень даже рабочий вариант! Спасибо!